# Custom moderator flag for sock puppeting suspicion was declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, sock-puppets

I moderator-flagged a user post, suspecting a cheating pattern. Within about 45 minutes they had two upvotes on the question post and one upvote on the self-answer post.
The answer seemed to indicate that the question problem was nonreproducible.

I moderator-flagged my sock-puppeting suspicion. I had in mind some comments in the [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) room that these kinds of flags are not declined.

Are they?

Comment: Flags like these are declined usually when a moderator cannot see the suspicion you saw. When you decide to flag, there should be something concrete rather than an unusual vote on a post.

Comment: This is not to discourage you from flagging issues like these, but rather to teach you that what you saw is not suspicious.

Comment: Of course there is a chance that the user is using sock puppets but moderators cannot see individual votes and without a solid pattern, there is no reason for escalation either.

Comment: People up vote all kinds of useless stuff. A single up vote is not a reason to flag. There is no pattern for moderators to look at. Even if we consider the two upvotes on the question, it could still be pretty much anyone.  However, if you can see that the recipient started upvoting others, then it could mean you found a sock puppet

Comment: Just FYI, mod flags cannot end with "disputed", they can only result in either "helpful" or "declined"... or "pending" for a very long time.

Comment: Or obviously, it can be retracted, but that's not something we mods can do for you

Comment: Generally I find that most users that use sockpuppets upvote their (low quality) content within *seconds* of it being posted or bulk upvote a few of their posts within seconds. 45 minutes later isn't normally very indicative of voting fraud unless you note that there were other votes on their posts at around the same time (were talking a minute or so here).

Comment: What is the point of posting a question like this in the abstract? If you are not allowing anybody to look at the question you are referring to, how can you expect any meaningful responses?

Comment: I assume they were hoping that @Dharman would have written what he wrote as 4 comments in the answer box...

Comment: @skomisa, I don't want to attract any negative attention to the post or the user. I thought it is understandable. It's not about that post, but about the general approach to this kind of situations

Comment: @ThomA, I saw the second upvote within 45min, not sure about the first

Comment: Once again, I am not able to see if there is a real sock puppetting or not, that's why mod flags exist. If we are not aloud to use flags to signal abnormal activity on a rather low quality post then I prefer to not flag or not moderate at all. Yes, I am that susceptible

Comment: 1 or 2 votes over 45 minutes isn't an indication of a pattern of vote fraud. No one is saying it isn't allowed to flag when you notice odd votes, but there has to be an actual pattern.

Comment: @skomisa There's no need for Vega to link to the question, as moderators can find it from Vega's list of declined flags. If the user/question is linked from an MSO question, then, unfortunately, there's significant risk of regular users acting inappropriately towards the linked post or author. Retaliatory downvoting (or other inappropriate actions) for *assumed* transgressions happen *way too often* in such cases. Regular users don't have the tools to look for voting patterns or sockpuppets, but do make assumptions and act on them. So, it's better to not have the flagged question linked here.

Comment: @Makyen (and Vega): OK, I understand the rationale for not wanting to reveal the actual post, and perhaps doubly so where the possibility of cheating is involved. That said, I'm now wondering about the value of this question on meta. Surely this could/should be treated instead as a private issue between the OP and the mods; I just don't see that the question (as it stands) is of much worth to the community. Also, if it is appropriate for this question not to link to the SO post, why is it regularly allowed for plenty of other meta questions where we see a positive/negative meta effect kick in?

Comment: Are you purposelz doing such things now?